# Authentication and Session management in react-native apps

Tags: reactjs, session, authentication, react-native

I've been looking at solutions for authenticating users on react-native based apps. I've  come across things like Firebase and JSON web tokens, however, I can't seem to find an example of session management between server and client device.

For the react/server relationship, the bit that I'm missing is the piece on the server side that is the equivalent of that `$_SESSION` variable in PHP, which can be used to store a user's unique ID.

```
=> Client token sent with each data request.
=> Request Checks token and sends data back for that specific user/token pair
```

I'm looking for some sort of example code on how this would be managed on the server-side and suggests on the tools/implementation you would suggest I use to implement it.

I'm not currently looking to implement oAuth2 because but rather I wish to create my own login system so I can properly understand how the App works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note about OAuth 2.0:**

I have a strong recommendation for [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) protocol when dealing with mobile applications, specially because of the Refresh Token architecture, that helps me keep my user authenticated for long periods of time without compromising their own security.

Also, this is the protocol used by major social SDKs: Google, Facebook, Twitter and Slack. The best part: you can use out-of-the box solutions in your server side, for example [OAuth 2.0 Server for PHP](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) and [OAuth 2.0 Server for NodeJS](https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server).

**Storing data safely on React Native**

Going back to the React Native end, once you have your set of credentials (JWT or OAuth 2.0), you have to store them safely. There is no direct way to do it using only the framework, but there is a great package called [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) that deals with it in both iOS and Android platforms.

Add it to your project.

```
# Using Yarn
yarn add react-native-keychain

# Or using NPM
npm install --save react-native-keychain
```

Then just use it where your user authenticates.

```js
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';


// When you have the JWT credentials
Keychain
  .setGenericPassword("JWT", token)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Credentials saved successfully!');
  });


// When you need to get it from safe storage
Keychain
  .getGenericPassword()
  .then(function(credentials) {
    console.log('Credentials successfully loaded for user:' + credentials.password);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Keychain couldn\'t be accessed! Maybe no value set?', error);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Luis, I totally plan to bring in OAuth 2.0 later. But currently at the learning/research stage and I'm keen to understand how it all works so I'm not creating stuff blissfully unaware of gaping holes I create because I'm sure how it works.

Comment: Yep, I agree. Still, the react native module will handle any kind of token or username + password credentials you have in mind.

Comment: Edit: Added "get" example for keychain

Comment: react-native-keychain is an excellent recommendation, I hadn't come across it.

Comment: Here is an example of node OAuth 2 server in action https://github.com/pedroetb/node-oauth2-server-example. For future readers.